# How to insert a dictionary inside list

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a list and add my dictionary `dict` inside that list like below 
Ex:

```
list1 =[]
dict1 = {'name': 'None', 'age':20, 'dead':'NO'}
```

I want this to look like `[{'name': 'None', 'age':20, 'dead':'NO'}]`

Comment: Your list is INVALID.

Comment: Did you mean: `[{'name': 'None', 'age':20, 'dead':'NO'}]`?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just as a note, if my above comment is indeed what you meant, just do `list.append(dict)`

Comment: @sshashank124 Yes thats what i meant

Comment: And another note, you probably shouldn't use `dict` or `list` as variable names, as they're already built in types

Comment: It is a really bad idea to use the names `list` and `dict` as variables. It will very likely come back to bite you if you do.

Comment: @BoarGules Noted

Comment: @sacul Thank you

Comment: @jaison, why not update your question as per comments and prevent further down-votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `[{'name': 'None', 'age':20, 'dead':'NO'}]` then try:

```
data_dict = {'name': 'None', 'age':20, 'dead':'NO'}
data_list =[data_dict]
```

Comment: Even better to just not need to do `list = []` at the start

Comment: exactly.. correct ..

Comment: @sshashank124 Thank you. That I would try

Comment: why not just `l = [{'name': 'None' ... }]`

Comment: Whatever the approach, the basic idea is to add the dict as the first element of the list whether that be through append, [dict], or [{...}]

Comment: I suggest you do not encourage the OP to use list and dict as variable names.

Comment: don't use list / dict as variable names